# android create movie from images

Tags: android, camera, movieclip, timelapse

It is possible to create a movie from images on a Android device without any external server resources ?

I would join about 500 snapshots from my SD card into a movie clip, with is playable on my phone.

I found several commercial tools for timelapsing recordings, but I want see how it is made.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android make animated video from list of images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images)