# Android make animated video from list of images

Tags: android, android-animation, video-processing, android-image

I want to make animated video from list of images by applying transition animation between two images. I found many similar questions on SO like,

[Android Screen capturing or make video from images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091794/android-screen-capturing-or-make-video-from-images)

[Android- How to make video using set of images from sd card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471212/android-how-to-make-video-using-set-of-images-from-sd-card)

All similar SO questions suggest to used animation for that, but how can we store that animated images to video file? Is there any Android library support this facility to make video of images?

Comment: do you find a way for your question ?

Comment: Written a possible solution for this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64839777/878126

Answer (score 8):

Android do not support for AWT's BufferedBitmap nor AWTUtil, that is for Java SE. Currently the solution with SequenceEncoder has been integrated into jcodec's Android version. You can use it from package org.jcodec.api.SequenceEncoder.

Here is the solution for generating MP4 file from series of Bitmaps using jcodec:

```
try {
    File file = this.GetSDPathToFile("", "output.mp4");
    SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(file);

    // only 5 frames in total
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        // getting bitmap from drawable path
        int bitmapResId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
        Bitmap bitmap = this.getBitmapFromResources(this.getResources(), bitmapResId);
        encoder.encodeNativeFrame(this.fromBitmap(bitmap));
    }
    encoder.finish();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// get full SD path
File GetSDPathToFile(String filePatho, String fileName) {
    File extBaseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (filePatho == null || filePatho.length() == 0 || filePatho.charAt(0) != '/')
        filePatho = "/" + filePatho;
    makeDirectory(filePatho);
    File file = new File(extBaseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + filePatho);
    return new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName);// file;
}

// convert from Bitmap to Picture (jcodec native structure)
public Picture fromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
    Picture dst = Picture.create((int)src.getWidth(), (int)src.getHeight(), ColorSpace.RGB);
    fromBitmap(src, dst);
    return dst;
}

public void fromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
    int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
    int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

    src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
            int rgb = packed[srcOff];
            dstData[dstOff]     = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
            dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
        }
    }
}
```

In case you need to change the fps, you may customize the SequenceEncoder.

Comment: What affect the video duration and how could we define it in this case? My code generated (I think) a 1-frame video.

Comment: And a (I think) 1-ms video.

Comment: There's no apparent customization for the SequenceEncoder.

Comment: this may be old but is there a way to set duration per image as of now ?

Comment: @morph85  encoder.encodeNativeFrame(this.fromBitmap(bitmap)); takes very long time (around a minute to execute). Any suggestion / solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pure java solution called JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ). Here's a **CORRECTED** simple class that does it using JCodec low-level API:

```
public class SequenceEncoder {
    private SeekableByteChannel ch;
    private Picture toEncode;
    private RgbToYuv420 transform;
    private H264Encoder encoder;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
    private CompressedTrack outTrack;
    private ByteBuffer _out;
    private int frameNo;
    private MP4Muxer muxer;

    public SequenceEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
        this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

        // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
        transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

        // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
        muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

        // Add video track to muxer
        outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

        // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
        _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

        // Create an instance of encoder
        encoder = new H264Encoder();

        // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
        // MP4
        spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    }

    public void encodeImage(BufferedImage bi) throws IOException {
        if (toEncode == null) {
            toEncode = Picture.create(bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight(), ColorSpace.YUV420);
        }

        // Perform conversion
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            Arrays.fill(toEncode.getData()[i], 0);
        transform.transform(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi), toEncode);

        // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
        _out.clear();
        ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

        // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
        spsList.clear();
        ppsList.clear();
        H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

        // Add packet to video track
        outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 25, 1, frameNo, true, null, frameNo, 0));

        frameNo++;
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
        outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils.createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

        // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
        muxer.writeHeader();
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SequenceEncoder encoder = new SequenceEncoder(new File("video.mp4"));
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(String.format("folder/img%08d.png", i)));
            encoder.encodeImage(bi);
        }
        encoder.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: BufferedImage and ImageIO are not supported in Android