# How do you record AR video processed by OpenCV on Android?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, video-processing, augmented-reality

I'm creating an Android app that makes use of OpenCV to implement augmented reality. One of the needed features is that it saves the processed video. I can't seem to find any sample code on real-time saving while using OpenCV.

If the above scenario isn't possible, another option is to save the video first and have it post-processed by OpenCV and saved back as a new file. But I can't find any sample code for this either.

Could someone be kind enough to point me to either direction, or give me an alternative? It's ok if the alternative doesn't use OpenCV.

Comment: you will have to look for an alternative, since currently opencv can neither read nor write video files on android

Answer (score 1):

Typical opencv flow is, you receive frames from camera, convert to RGB format, perform matrix operations then return to activity to display in View. You can actually store the modified frames as images somewhere in sdcard and use jcodec to create your mp4 out of your images. See [Android make animated video from list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images).